# Generator-based for loop and list-based for loop turns out different output?

Tags: python, loops, generator

Here is the code

```
def func(x):
    print(x)
    return x

for x in (func(i) for i in range(2)):
    print(x)
print('-'*20)

for x in [func(i) for i in range(2)]:
    print(x)
```

This is the output

```
0
0
1
1
--------------------
0
1
0
1
```

Why do they have the different result? i.e, what does python do about (i for i in range(2)) and [i for i in range(2)]

Comment: With a generator, `func` is called lazily.  With a list, it is called eagerly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `(func(i) for i in range(2))` you're creating a [generator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/) that is evaluated *lazily* (the `func()` isn't called immediately),

With `[func(i) for i in range(2)]` you first create list with list-comprehension (`func()` is called) and then you iterate over this list in `for`-loop.

Comment: Yes, I could understand the list part. But why for generator, two zero is printed together? i.e, why the output is 0 0 1 1. Doesn't it should be only 0 1?

Comment: Since it's a sequence, it's executed when looped. For the first iteration, it's roughly equivalent to `print(func(0))`

Comment: @AltmanJeffry No, when `for`-loop calls for next value of the generator, the `range()` supplies first `0` to `func()` - func prints `0` and returns `0`. Inside the for-loop you print second `0`. And so on.